# Form Load takes parameters for scheduled tasks

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

Please have a look at the code below:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim objPerson As New clsPerson
    Dim strCommandLine() As String
    strCommandLine = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

    If strCommandLine(1) = "Test1" Then
        objPerson.Test1()
    ElseIf strCommandLine(1) = "Test2" Then
        objPerson.Test2()
    ElseIf strCommandLine(1) = "Test3" Then
        objPerson.Test3()
    End If
End Sub
```

One of three methods is executed depending on whether the scheduled task passes a parameter of `Test1`, `Test2` or `Test3`.  This is obviously not very well designed.

Is there a design pattern to meet this requirement? Something similar to the Model View Presenter pattern perhaps.  This is a Windows Forms application with no user interface (that an end user can interact with).

Comment: This code belongs in a Main() function, not a Load event handler.  Use the Select statement.

Comment: if i understand your question, you can use the [Enum Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Where to begin?  If it has "no user interface" then perhaps it should be a Console application?

Comment: @Hans Passant, thanks for the comment. I have taken your advice (after doing some research of my own). Can you post an answer so that I can give some credit? +1.

Comment: @tcarvin, good point but I intend to set this up as an application client in future.  +1.